# script doesnt fire with google sheets

Tags: javascript

```
function emailNotification() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
 var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
 var recipient = "jt@gmail.com";
 var subject = 'Update to '+sheet.getName();
 var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes on cell: «' + cell + '» New cell value: «' + cellvalue + '»';
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
 };
```

The top script works when I use the run function but if I edit the spreadsheet that it is bound to it does not.
For some reason the script is never firing, what am I doing wrong?
I am a complete neophyte so please provide an example.
Thanks in advance``

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `function emailNotification() {` to `function onEdit() {`

Then in the script editor click on the 'Resources' menu and select 'All your triggers' add a new 'onEdit' in events select 'From spreadsheet'and 'On edit'.

[image: All your triggers window]

Comment: Thank you sir, that was the missing link, works like a charm :-)

Comment: I notice that now after every cell is edited an individual email gets sent.

Comment: Is there a way to make this so that you can make certain edits and after say five minutes only one email gets sent for all the editing you've done within that five minutes?